# Magento 2 stores->configuration not loading. Stuck on infinite loading with no errors

Tags: magento2, bug

Im developing a magento 2 site using WSL on windows 11. And for some reason my configuration page is not loading.

Area in question is stores->configuration.

Things i have tried:

- disabling all external modules and compiled
- setting correct permissions to all files
- setting correct ownership of files
- ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento indexer:reindex && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US -f && bin/magento c:f` multiple times after each potential fix.
- reimported db

All other areas of the admin work correctly, just the configuration is broken.

I am running magento 2.4.0 | php 7.4 | nginx | elasticsearch

Image of problem
[image: What Is happening]

Comment: I should add, i have checked the contents of /var/log/nginx/error.log and nothing is in here. Also the contents of var/log within my root magento folder

Answer (score 0):

did you find any solution for the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was WSL 1 issue. Once I changed it to WSL 2 it is working fine.